# Airplay Txt Record

Tags: ios, bonjour, airplay

I'm publishing a `NetService` for Airplay in an iOS app, but am unsure if I have my txt record correct. Specifically, I'm not sure what the `pk` and `pi` values are suppose to be.

Here's the txt record I'm using:

```
{
deviceid = "xxxxx";
features = "0x5A7FFFF7,0xE";
flags = 0x44;
model = "AppleTV3,1";
pi = "43f884bc-eb56-459d-a307-9cce844f86bf";
pk = 8b197524a8f78819b8e64b8d8cd4a70faec1b49317e517fb81f624628a313a39;
srcvers = "220.68";
vv = 2;
}
```

Right now, I just have values I found online for `pk` and `pi`. What exactly are those fields for and what should their values be?